# File not uploading to s3 bucket using yii2tech/file-storage extension

Tags: amazon-s3, yii2, file-storage

I'm trying to upload file to my amazon s3 bucket.
My config looks like this

```
'fileStorage' => [
                    'class' => 'yii2tech\filestorage\amazon\Storage',
                     'awsKey' => 'dota2',
                     'awsSecretKey' => 'dota2',
                     'buckets' => [
                                'webfiles' => [
                                'fileSubDirTemplate' => '{ext}/{^name}/{^^name}',
                                'region' => 'us_e1',
                                'acl' => 'public',
                                 ],
                       ]
                ],
```

My upload function looks like this

```
$bucket = Yii::$app->fileStorage->getBucket('webfiles');        

    $bucket->copyFileIn('/var/www/html/vasttag/web/', 'samplefinal.mp4');
    $result= var_dump($bucket->fileExists('samplefinal.mp4'));
    echo $result;
```

I get result as false. Yes I have double checked my path and my filename. Its perfectly fine. Anyone know where Im going wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with information what is the value of `$model->Ad` exactly?

Comment: @Bizley done edited

Comment: Obviously the first path is empty (no file name) - it should be full file path. The second argument in copyFileIn is the target file name so it's fine.

Comment: @Bizley added the filename to the first argument..still getting false. BTW my s3 target folder is webfiles/vastfiles. Is my config correct?

Comment: Double check if your file is really at this path `/var/www/html/vasttag/web/samplefinal.mp4`. Have you got this `webfiles/vastfiles` folder configured at all? I don't see this in your configuration.

Comment: @Bizley yeah ive checked, its there. And yes I really dont know how to configure the target s3 folder. I thougth `'fileSubDirTemplate' => '{ext}/{^name}/{^^name}',` would do it

Comment: If you send this file with current configuration it will appear in your bucket path: `mp4/s/a`.